# Trouble with css scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a problem with my nav scroll. I would just scroll the nav but I can't.

Here is my JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nqh4mwg/)

For see my problem you must click on menu

If anyone have a solution I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 problems.

First, `.mask` has `z-index` of 10000 whereas it should be less than `.pushmenu`.

Second, `.pushmenu` should have `overflow-y` set to `auto`, this will add the scrollbar automatically when the content height exceeds its container height. In this case, the window's height.

```
.mask {
    z-index: 999; /* change this accordingly--must be less than .pushmenu's z-index */
}
.pushmenu {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1nqh4mwg/1/)